# Error [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES] on one device only?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jar-signing

I'm working on an Android app that has was originally released two years ago and has been successfully updated maybe 8-12 times.  While doing internal testing, we found that one of our devices will display this error when we try to install a new APK onto it:

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

This error is pretty well documented around the web, and the commonly cited source of the problem is having JDK7 installed on your system, but I am still using JDK6.

But what is really odd to me is that the APK reports being signed correctly using the "jarsigner" tool, and the APK also installs correctly on three other devices I've tested on.  Only our Droid Pro w/ Android 2.2 seems to be reporting this installation error.

Has anyone else ever run into this issue only occurring on a single device?  It is a bit troubling, but I'm not sure whether it is a problem with the app or a problem with the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encoutered similar problem with devices 2.1 and 2.2
Using JDK6 didn't help, but manually signing with jarsigner, providing sigalg and digestalg - did (even with JDK7):

```
jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withDSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore keystore.keystore file.apk alias
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like you're right.  To be more specific, our app uses Unity, which performs the signing process automatically as part of its build process.  There appears to be a bug in the latest version (4.2) that is causing this problem on some devices.




To resolve, I did have to manually sign and align the APK file.  The exact steps I followed can be found here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/192147-4-2-and-keystore-problem-on-Nook-Color?p=1340508

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the problem with the device. Is the app built for 2.2, froyo, api level 9 (your device OS version). Check the manifest file of your app once..

Comment: We are currently using a min-sdk level 7 and a target sdk level of 14.